# create vm using pyvmomi module from .vmx and .vmdk files

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I have been trying to create a new vm with using existing vm's .vmx and .vmdk files from ESX host in Python using pyvmomi module. 
I am new to pyvmomi and there isnt much online help available for pyvmomi. I have checked sample code in github(https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/tree/298bf74446f3fcc5743d6435763ff6dc16ab4cbc/samples) but no relevent things found. 
Please provide me pointers.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a clone. Is that correct?

Comment: I am working on backup-restore project where I have to restore existing vm/create a new vm out of previously backed up .vmx and vmdk files.

Comment: When you do this will the original VirtualMachine using that vmx and vmdk file be in the inventory, or will this be at a new location so it will be considered a new virtualmachine to the host or vcenter?

Comment: Hi Mike, It will be considered new vm. It is stateless, so it could be new host or same host anything.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say the Virtualachine name is: **1001-web1.myhost.com**

Then the HostSystem you want to put it on is: **host1.myesxhost.com**

The host has a datastore called: **Local1**

The host lives in a Folder called: **Prod**

You need to get the files from the VM into the Local1 datastore. Ill let you figure that part out. They need to be placed into a folder called: **1001-web1.myhost.com**

Next you need to find the Folder **Prod** and the HostSystem **host1.myesxhost.com** in the inventory so you have the ManagedObjectRef for them. You can use a searchIndex.FindByDnsName to find the host, and a searchIndex.FindByInventoryPath to find the Folder (or a few other methods..)

Once you have located the Folder **Prod** you can use a [RegisterVM_Task](http://pubs.vmware.com/vi30/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.Folder.html#registerVm) to register the vm.

```
si = connect.SmartConnect(xxx)
host = si.content.searchIndex.FindByDnsName(None,"host1.myesxhost.com", False)
folder = si.content.searchIndex.FindByInventoryPath(xxx)
task = folder.RegisterVM_Task(path="[Local1] 1001-web1.myhost.com/1001-web1.myhost.com.vmx", name="new vm name", asTemplate=False, pool=None, host=host)
```

From here you should be able to monitor the process of the task once its completed successfully the task.info.result will contain the MOREF of the new VM.

This is pseudo code so the syntax may be off but this is the process you will have to follow.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the datastore path to the vmx file you can use the following:

```
from pyVim import folder

folder.Register("[datastore]TestVM/TestVM.vmx")
```